# Unable to find pyenv python interpreter by tox

Tags: python, testing, pyenv, tox

I have a simple `tox.ini` as below

```
[tox]
min_version = 4.0
env_list =
    py{37,38,39,310}-drf{314}

[testenv]
envdir = {toxworkdir}/venvs/{envname}

[testenv:py{37,38,39,310}-drf{314}]
commands = python -m pytest tests/test_rest_framework
deps =
    pytest
    -e .[dev]
    drf314: djangorestframework>=3.14,<3.15
```

and I have multiple Python versions installed on my local machine

```
$ pyenv versions 
                                                                                                                                                                        
* system (set by /home/jpg/.pyenv/version)
* 3.10.3 (set by /home/jpg/.pyenv/version)
  3.6.15
* 3.7.13 (set by /home/jpg/.pyenv/version)
  3.8.11
* 3.8.13 (set by /home/jpg/.pyenv/version)
* 3.9.11 (set by /home/jpg/.pyenv/version)
  3.9.9


$ ls -ls /usr/bin/python*   
                                                                                                                                                             
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7*
3580 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3662032 Jul  1  2022 /usr/bin/python2.7*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Jul  1  2022 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 15  2022 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8*
5368 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5494552 Mar 13 15:56 /usr/bin/python3.8*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Mar 13 15:56 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config*
5668 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5803968 Nov 23  2021 /usr/bin/python3.9*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Nov 23  2021 /usr/bin/python3.9-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.9-config*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config*
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Jan 25 14:03 /usr/bin/python3-futurize*
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 Jan 25 14:03 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2-config*
```

But, if I run the `tox` command, I get an error that says the interpreter is not found.

```
$ tox -e py37  
                                                                                                                                                                        
py37: skipped because could not find python interpreter with spec(s): py37
  py37: SKIP (0.08 seconds)
  evaluation failed :( (0.16 seconds)
```

**Question**: How can I tell the `tox` to use `Python 3.7`?

**Note**: I'm using tox 4.6.0

```
$ tox --version   
                                                                                                                                                                       
4.6.0 from /home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/keycloak-auth-utils-T3AadZoL/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tox/__init__.py
```

Comment: What about the other Python versions? Does Tox work fine with those?

Comment: Yes, tox works just fine with 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10

Comment: Odd. What version is your system Python? Perhaps there is some conflict (if it's 3.7) that Tox can't resolve.... hang on, I see the output: 2.7 and 3.8; unlikely the cause.

Comment: What is the result of `which python3.7`?

Comment: its empty @JürgenGmach

Comment: I think `tox` only considers the global interpreters, and omitting the `pyenv` choices

Comment: but I assume you set `pyenv global system 3.10.3 3.7.13 3.8.13 3.9.11`, given the output of `pyenv versions`. Unless you set those locally in a directory and forgot to mention that; I have assumed that output is for the globally available Python versions.

Comment: I had the same problem with Tox 4.9.0. It found versions 3.8, 3.9, 3.11, but for 3.10 I got this error. Maybe it is caching problem? I removed the .tox directory and tried again, but got the same error.

Comment: Note that this message may be misleading because it also shows up for problems otherwise related to building your package. For example, I saw this because of a syntax error in my setup.cfg. The crucial thing for me was to study the stack traces and error messages in the output above; for me they showed up as indented blocks of red print.